# Actualizar pestaña

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo la ruta **localhost:3000/index**  que muestra la información de unas imagenes y videos, en la ruta **localhost:3000/conf** en la cual cambio la manera en que salen las imagenes y videos, pero despues de crear los cambios tengo que actualizar la ruta **/index** para que se vean los cambios, lo que necesito es saber alguna forma de que cuando por ejemplo: en la ruta **conf** le de al boton salvar se actualise la pestaña de la ruta **/index**

```
$('#btn-save').click(function(){
   //codigo para actualizar ruta /index
})
```

Comment: mira , en /index yo muestro la inform con una conf q cargo de un fichero ,  y en /conf cambio la info de ese fichero , y necesito desp q cambie la conf actualizar la ruta /index para q carge la nueva configuracion del fichero, pero sin tener q estar en la pestanna y darle f5

Comment: usa header('Location: http://www.example.com/'); de php o window.location.replace("index.php"); de js ambas recargan la pagina como si hicieras un f5 o refrescaras la pagina adentro tienes que poner la direccion a la que te redirige o si vas a recargar la pagina en la que estas pon de nuevo tu direccion header('Location: paginaQueRefrescaras.php');

Comment: debes subir mas codigo esas dos lineas no sirven de mucho

Answer (score 0):

si quieres refrescar una pagina despues de hacer una modificacion en la base de datos.

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
window.location.replace("index.php");


    $('#btn-save').click(function(){
   //codigo para actualizar ruta /index
window.location.replace("ruta/index.php");
})
```

la primera es php y la segunda es por javascript adentro va el la ruta  del archivo actualizar

Comment: yo uso js nada mas, **window.location.replace("archivo");**  lo que hace es llevarme a esa ruta , yo no quiero ir a la ruta , yo quiero que esa ruta se actualice sola despues de yo salvar los cambios

Comment: perdon pero no entiendo a que te refieres con actualizar la ruta , pense que querias que te recargara esa ruta.

Comment: @Travv lo que quieres hacer se llama ajax, debes consultar un poco sobre eso y hacer la pregunta sobre el problema específico que presentes a la hora de intentarlo